# Understanding the triangle inequality of the essential supremum norm.(Royden 4th edition on pg.138)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

The proof is given below:

> [image]
>   [image]

**My question is:**

1-it is not clear for me what is the idea they used to prove that $\| f\|_{\infty}$ is an essential upper bound for $f$ and what is the $E_{n}$ used in that case. could anyone explains this for me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|f\|_{\infty}$ is defined as the infimum of all positive  numbers $M$ such that $|f| \leq M$ almost everywhere. Since $\|f\|_{\infty}+\frac 1 n >\|f\|_{\infty}$ it follows that there exits $M$ such that $|f| \leq M$ almost everywhere and $\|f\|_{\infty}+\frac 1 n>M$. Take $E_n=\{x\in E: |f| > M\}$. This $E_n$ has the stated properties.

Comment: It is not clear for me how  your $E_{n}$ satisfies the stated properties could you clarify this? also I was given a hint that $$E_{n} \{ x \in E | \quad  |f(x)| > \| f\|_{\infty } + \frac{1}{n}\}.$$ does this $E_{n}$ satisfies the stated property also?

Comment: Yes, this $E_n$ also works fine. @Mathstupid

Comment: Now, I do not understand why both $E_{n}$ works fine. could you provide more details please? I really do not understand

Comment: It seems for me your $E_{n}$ is the opposite of my $E_{n}$

Comment: @Mathstupid No. My $E_n$ also works fine. I am just taking $M$ between $\|f\|_{\infty} $ and $\|f\|_{\infty}+\frac 1 n $.

Comment: What about the other $E_{n},$ where is it taking $M$?

Comment: @Mathstupid I am taking $M<\|f\|_{\infty}+\frac 1 n$ but they are saying that we can as well take $M=\|f\|_{\infty}+\frac 1 n$. In my argument $M\leq \|f\|_{\infty}+\frac 1 n$ is good enough so what they are saying is correct.

Comment: What about the argument in the other $E_{n}$? where is it taking $M$?

Comment: @Mathstupid If you take $M=\|f\|_{\infty}+\frac 1  n$ then the two $E_n$'s are one and the same, right?

Comment: yes, but it is not clear for me the idea before creating this $E_{n}$ (what criteria should those $E_{n}$ satisfies) and why we are defining them?